# get_categories returns an array with one category

Tags: categories

I'm running a query on a custom plugin to display all categories and put them into a dropdown (the select parts are outside the loop) which looks like this:

```
<?php
$ember_categories = get_categories();
foreach($ember_categories as $ember_category) {
    echo '<option value="' . $ember_category->cat_ID . '">' . $ember_category->name . '</option>';
}
?>
```

For some reason though, it's only returning my default category (Uncategorized) - even though there are six more added to the system (including one I added afterwards, just as a curiosity). I'm wondering whether I'm doing something glaringly wrong?

Comment: Doh! Should probably have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Hey. Just saw that you removed the check mark for the solution. Could you please leave a comment on the answer, so it can be improved for later readers?

Comment: Apologies - didn't mean to remove the check, I clicked it so it would accept your answer. Returned now, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `get_categories( array('hide_empty' => 0 ) );`